# Repeated function resulting in quadratic time.

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

Let $$r(f, x) = k$$ such that

$$f^k (x) < 2 \hbox{ and } f^{k-1} (x) \geq 2$$

For example $$r(n \rightarrow n-1, 2^n) = 2^n-1; r(n \rightarrow n/2, 2^n) = n.$$

For an arbitrary $c$, we have $$r( n \rightarrow n/2^{1/c}, 2^n) = cn$$.

Question, for an arbitrary $c$, is there some closed form function $f$ such that

$$r(f, 2^n) = n^c$$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Title refers to "quadratic time", body doesn't. Que?

Comment: Maybe the asker is thinking of the specific case where $r(f,2^n) = n^2$?

Comment: Maybe. But it's asker's job to post a clear, unambiguous question, not our job to guess what asker means. 

Comment: The answer is: "Yes, there is such a function".